# Could a DTMF implementation like Google Tone be used as a practical file transfer mechanism?

Tags: audio, file-transfer

Google recently released a Chrome extension called [Tone](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-tone/nnckehldicaciogcbchegobnafnjkcne), that allows sharing of a URL between two computers, using their microphones and speakers to encode the information in an audio signal.  It uses DTMF technology, similar to touch-tone signals used for telephone switching over voice-frequency lines.

The technology is only practical between two computers in close enough proximity for audio transmission.  That constraint aside, how would the speed of this technology compare relative to other file transfer technologies, for example a phoneline modem or WiFi?

Comment: User [Fuzzy Toothpaste](http://superuser.com/users/493617/fuzzytoothpaste) attempted to ask this question but the question was deleted before I could figure out how to help them ask it in an on-topic way.

Comment: How long is a piece of string? How big is the file and how long can you wait? Without that info the answer is "yes". There's no point where one form of data transfer becomes unsuitable for file transfer in all cases.

Comment: Wow, someone re-invented the dial-up modem...

Comment: DTMF would actually give you 16 tone combinations, which means you could transmit 4 bits with each tone. It would be kind of like ISDN on steroids. And you could do it even on a line with load coils. I guess the question is how many tones can you transmit a second. If memory serves, for dialing purposes the minimum duration for each tone is 250 milliseconds. For this to be useable, you'd have reduce that a lot (too late to do the math).

Comment: @Tetsujin, aDSL is actually like having 256 simultaneous dial-up modems on one line.

Comment: @Bob: Yeah, I struggled with that.  I reframed the question a little.  Thanks.

Comment: @BillOer: I don't know how the limitations of working with an open air audio signal would compare to hard wire, but 4 tones per second at 4 bits per tone would give you a whopping 2 bytes per second.  If thats even within an order of magnitude, that would pretty much answer the question.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 I did the math, and 2 bytes per second is the correct order of magnitude - I worked a maximum of 40 bits per second = 5 bits per second.

Comment: [Of course](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/10/meet-badbios-the-mysterious-mac-and-pc-malware-that-jumps-airgaps/) ;-) *"Ruiu said he arrived at the theory about badBIOS's high-frequency networking capability after observing encrypted data packets [...]. The packets were transmitted even when the laptop had its Wi-Fi and Bluetooth cards removed. [...]. Even then, forensic tools showed the packets continued to flow over the airgapped machine. Then, when Ruiu removed the internal speaker and microphone connected to the airgapped machine, the packets suddenly stopped."*

Comment: Maybe Tone is not even sending URLs, but just codes that the extension changes into a URL by asking Google's servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is theoretically doable, but not practical for transferring anything but the smallest of files.  The minimum pulse duration (including inter-digit interval) is apparently [100msec](http://nemesis.lonestar.org/reference/telecom/signaling/dtmf.html) for ANSI compliance.  So doing some trivial math -

16 DTMF tones (assuming we can use them all) can represent 4 bits of information.   at 100ms per tone+inter-tone interval we can do 10 tones a second, this gives us a maximum speed of 40 bits per second - which means to transmit a tiny 2kbyte file (which equates to say 1 screen of 80 x 25 text) would take more then 5 minutes.

To put it in perspective

1. The first modems I was aware of - and I've been doing it a while -
   were "[accoustic couplers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_coupler)" which ran at 300 bits per second or
   10 times as fast in the 1960's.
2. The first modem I used, and among the earliest proper modems - probably
   30 years ago was 2400 bps or 60 times as fast (Mid 1980's)
3. A
   typical analog modem-modem connection would be 33.6k or 840 times as
   fast.    (Early 1990's to current.  You can get faster downstream
   connections   if connecting to an ISDN modem on the other side)
4. A slow 1 megabit broadband connection would be 25000 times as fast. (late 90's tech)

Comment: In your comparison, you left off the most relevant case: two guys with hearing aids talking morse code over two cans and a piece of string.  "dot dash dot."  "What?"  "dot dash dot"  "Come again?" "dot dash dot" "What?"

Comment: Yup.  Never thought of morse code.   Its a good comparison technology.

Comment: I think Google's Tone is even a one-way protocol; the morse-code receiver would not even be able to respond "What?", I think, @fixer1234. (But I know the question is broader than just Tone. And maybe Tone itself has some fault-tolerance built-in, just like QR codes.)

Answer (score 1):

Today's best modulation schemes can only encode *maybe* 5 bits per second per Hertz of bandwidth. Human-audible frequencies are only from about 15 Hz to 22kHz, so only about 22kHz of bandwidth max, so 110kbps (13KiBytes/sec).

With audiophile-quality equipment (192 kHz sampling rate), you can sample and hopefully reproduce ultrasonic frequencies up to 96kHz. So 470kbps (57KiBytes/sec) max.

Pretty crappy by today's standards. Not really viable for file transfer.

(And this is based on fully using the entire available frequency range with complicated modulation that sounds like white noise, not limited to DTMF. Limiting yourself to DTMF would be much much worse.)

Comment: Unless Google is using some enhanced version of DTMF, it's limited to a total of 16 fixed two-tone combinations.  Those aren't even being modulated to carry information, they are the information.  So, it sounds like "crappy" doesn't begin to describe it.  :-)